# Retrofit works but callback doesn't call success or failure methods - Android Fragment

Tags: android, callback, retrofit

```
public void getApiCallToLoadData() {
    Log.e("test","in method");
    mService.getResponse().enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Example> call, Response<Example> response) {
            Log.e("test", "success");
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
             //   mAdapter.updateAnswers(response.body().getItems());
                Log.e("AnswersPresenter", "posts loaded from API");
               mList = response.body().getVideoAPIResponse();
            }else {
                int statusCode  = response.code();
                // handle request errors depending on status code
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Example> call, Throwable t) {
            showErrorMessage();
            Log.e("test", "error loading from API");

        }
    });

    Log.e("test","out method");
}
```

Api successfully hit and i got response in my retrofit logs but it does not call onresponse or onfailure methods. help required.

Comment: post your model/pojo class also post your json response

Comment: I would guess that your `Example` class doesn't have the correct structure.

Comment: Example doesnot match the response type I guess

Comment: You haven't logged anything in the else condition of `(response.isSuccessful())`